# Is there a way to start a task before node.js server.listen event is emitted?

Tags: express, server

I want to be able to start an async task before the server starts listen to the port and gets requests, 
my workaround was to invoke my task from the onListening function and when my task is done I'm binding the port to the address - but that workaround is ugly..

```
    function onListening() {
        var addr = server.address();
        var bind;
// Following service gets the default plugins from the yamls and stores them in the DB.
        defaultOperationsService.getOOTBOperations().then(function success() {
            logger.info('Done getting default plugins operations!');

        }, function err(err) {
            logger.error('Error while trying to get operations' + err);

        }).done(function done() {
            bind = typeof addr === 'string' ? 'pipe ' + addr : 'port ' + addr.port;
            logger.debug('Listening on ' + bind);
        });
    }
```

Comment: I was introduced to a better way and probably the best way, call server.listen(port) when done:  defaultOperationsService.getOOTBOperations().then(function success(){
    logger.info('Done getting default plugins operations!');

}, function err(err){
    logger.error('Error while trying to get operations' + err);

}).done(function done(){
    server.listen(port);
});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was introduced to a better way and probably the best way, call server.listen(port) when done:

```
 defaultOperationsService.getOOTBOperations().then(function success(){
    logger.info('Done getting default plugins operations!');

}, function err(err){
    logger.error('Error while trying to get operations' + err);

}).done(function done(){
    server.listen(port);
});
```

Comment: You have no idea how much this helped me, thank you !

Comment: @hereForLearing I'm glad :)) do it with async await it will be prettier :)

Comment: Yes that what I'm doing, it's just the idea that I didn't think about :)